# divs positioning for a chat message

Tags: css

I want to create chat component in such a way that if I display all its elements it will look like the following:

[image]

and if I remove most of the elements, the message will be shown in this way:

[image]

However my code has 4 problems:

1. the picture and the bubble element are not next to each other
2. the speech bubble do not get shorter with less text;
3. the text in the bubble doesn't centre vertically on its parent div, rather on the upper parent container;
4. the day-time element stay fix on the right, rather than being aligned to the right side of the speech-bubble.

I tried many options, but the more I touch the CSS, the more issues I create.

Any suggestion on how to achieve the desired result?

This is my code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}

.upper-text {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 120%;
}

.message-container {
  width: auto;
}

.character-picture {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: inline-block;
}

.buble-wrapper {
  max-width: 75%;
  height: auto;
}

.speech-bubble {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.message {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 4%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.lower-tex {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 120%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="upper-text">Name</div>
    <div class="message-container">
      <div class="character-picture"></div>
      <div class="buble-wrapper">
        <div class="speech-bubble">
          <div class="message">text message</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower-tex">Monday: 20:38</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for. There is a lot of room for improvement, but this will get you started.

I've removed some of the html you had that I thought unnecessary and changed how you size and place some elements.

I suggest you take a look at CSS Flexbox and Grid, they allow you to do complex layouts like this in a breeze.

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.upper-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.message-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.character-picture {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.message {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.lower-tex {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="upper-text">Name</div>
    <div class="message-container">
      <div class="character-picture"></div>
      <div class="message">text message example wow this text wraps very well</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower-tex">Monday: 20:38</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you @DoHn, how about browser support of Grid and Flexbox?

Comment: Sure, that has to be taken into a count. But if you're building a chat you're probably going to need other recent features anyway like WebSockets and so on. It's a matter of what you think your target is. Building a chat layout purely using floats and other older browser compatible features is a lot more cumbersome and sometimes not worth it, but if you need it go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by DoHn, you can achieve this using flex or grid.
Below is the solution using grid.
Read more here [complete-guide-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid)

For browser support, checkout https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px auto;
  grid-gap: 2px 4px;
  width: 360px;
}

.upper-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 120%;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.message-container {
  width: auto;
}

.character-picture {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.speech-bubble {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2;
  justify-self: stretch;
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.message {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.lower-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 120%;
  justify-self: end;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="upper-text">Name</div>
  <div class="character-picture"></div>
  <div class="speech-bubble">
    <div class="message">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley o</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lower-text">Monday: 20:38</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you make the bubble shorter if the message is few words only? (e.g. 'Lorem Ipsum)

Comment: Update justify-self: start; for speech-bubble class

Comment: yes, that's work, but the lower-text element does not follow the shorter bubble and stay on the far right of the grid. So the question really is how do we shorten the bubble and make the lower-text remain aligned with it?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .chat-log {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.left-side {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.right-side {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  float: right;
}

.text {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail span.caption {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 30%;
  left: 10%;
}

.msg {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px;
}

.msg::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 79%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -20px;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f0f0f0 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.time{
  float: right;
  margin-right:10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chat-log">
    <div class="left-side">
      <div class="text">
        Name
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <span class="caption">image</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
      <div class="msg">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum tempore           inventore architecto a voluptatum ratione, sunt doloribus nobis iure             debitis? Veniam.
      </div>
      <div class="time">Monday 5:13 PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you. I do not use flexbox or grid I have made it simple.